# Programmatically downloading file

Tags: c#, http

Using C# 4.5,I'm trying to programmatically log-on to a third-party website and then download a csv file from another page on that site.
I tried using following approach.I dont get any errors but it seems to download the contents of their logon page and save it as a csv file instead of the actual csv file having data.

Also,if I read the response stream after logging in, I see that I'm getting the log-on webpage back.

What am I missing here please?
Plus, I need to post the name of the form as well.How do I achieve that?Please advise.

Update:I tried using CookieContainer in request object, but still no luck..I get the same result.

Thanks.

```
//Log-on to website and post user and password
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, myLogonURL);
    request.Content = new StringContent("{\"user\":\"abcd\",\"password\":test}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                                                            
    var sendTask = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    var response = sendTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    //Download the file
    request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, fileDownloadURL);
    sendTask = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    response = sendTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var httpStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();


    //Save the downloaded file
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(downloadedFilePath))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpStream)) {
        httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is successfully logging in?

Comment: Doesnt look like so.Have updated my question.Thanks.

Comment: if you are using `await` you should not have `.Result` anywhere in your function. just do `var send = await client.SendAsync(...` and replace all your `sendTask.Result` with `send`

Comment: Hi Scott...please see my answer below...would you be able to advise on that please?Thanks.